# NullPointerException When calling Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

i want to create Dialog using fragment following this [link][1],

Here my code for dialog fragment

```
public class AlertFragmentDialog extends DialogFragment 
{   
    public static final int DIALOG_EXIT_ALERT = 1;

    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "titles";
    private static final String KEY_DIALOG = "dialogtype";

    public static DialogFragment newInstance(int _title,int _dialogType){
        AlertFragmentDialog frag = new AlertFragmentDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(KEY_TITLE, _title);
        args.putInt(KEY_DIALOG, _dialogType);
        frag.setArguments(args);        
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        switch(getArguments().getInt(KEY_DIALOG))
        {
            case DIALOG_EXIT_ALERT : 
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle(getArguments().getInt(KEY_TITLE))
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.global_yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                            {
                                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doYesConfirmationClick();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.global_no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                            {
                                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).doNoConfirmationClick();
                            }
                        }).create();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And call it using this code

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        DialogFragment alertDialog = AlertFragmentDialog.newInstance(R.string.global_exit_alert,AlertFragmentDialog.DIALOG_EXIT_ALERT);
        alertDialog.show(fm, "dialog");
```

But when i run i got error NullPointerException on my emulator.
Error at alertDialog.show(fm, "dialog");
Please help i'm not sure what's wrong with my code..

Comment: Whats in your logcat? NullpointerExceptions show you the line where the error happens. Check this lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static DialogFragment newInstance(int _title,int _dialogType){
    AlertFragmentDialog frag = new AlertFragmentDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(KEY_TITLE, _title);
    args.putInt(KEY_DIALOG, _dialogType);
    frag.setArguments(args);        
    return frag;  // you were returning null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `newInstance()` returns `null`. Change it to return `frag`.